# What is the data type?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am using ADB2C's custom policies to create the screens.
What are the variable names and data types for user IDs and passwords in login and MFA?
Also, what are the variable names and data types for the phone number and confirmation code in MFA?
I don't know because it is not the source I described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

•   According to the official Microsoft documentation, the *username* in Azure AD B2C custom policy is denoted by a variable attribute of **‘signInNames.userName’** and its datatype is **‘String’**. Similarly, for password, the variable attribute assigned is **‘password’** and its datatype is **‘String’**. For the *phone number*, the assigned attribute is **‘mobile’** or **‘mobilePhone’** and the datatype is **‘String’** but if you want to use that *phone number for MFA* in Azure AD B2C, the variable attribute for it is **‘strongAuthenticationAlternativePhoneNumber’** and its datatype is **‘String’**. Rest for the *confirmation code*, there is no such defined attribute by default in Azure AD B2C as others specified earlier, but you can surely define a custom attribute for it by defining the **‘DisplayName’, ‘DataType’** and **‘UserInputType’** for the custom attribute as below: -

```
  <!-- 
   <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema> -->
<ClaimType Id="city">
  <DisplayName>City where you work</DisplayName>
  <DataType>string</DataType>
  <UserInputType>DropdownSingleSelect</UserInputType>
  <Restriction>
    <Enumeration Text="Berlin" Value="berlin" />
    <Enumeration Text="London" Value="london" />
    <Enumeration Text="Seattle" Value="seattle" />
  </Restriction>
</ClaimType>
 <!-- 
  </ClaimsSchema>
 </BuildingBlocks>-->
```

For more information regarding the above, please refer the below documentation links: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-user-input?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#define-a-claim

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes